# How to check if a variable has a value in a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to check whether a variable has a value or not.

```
declare @name varchar(20)

set @name = (SELECT Product_Name 
             FROM tb_new_product_Name_id 
             WHERE Product_Name = @productName)

 if (@name )   // here I need to check it
```

How to do it? thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
if (@name is null or @value = '') //it will indicate whether it contains a value or not
```

Comment: What is `@value` referring to here? I don't see an `@value` variable in OP's post

Answer (score 6):

Just do the [`IF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) directly, using [`EXISTS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) instead:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tb_new_product_Name_id 
        where Product_Name=@productName)
BEGIN
    --Do something because a row existed with that name
END
```

We may be able to further assist with simplifying your code if you told us more on what you were planning to do having confirmed a row existed in `tb_new_product_Name_id`. It looks like you're writing very procedural code - first I'll do X, then I'll do Y, then I'll do Z, etc. SQL excels as a language where you tell it "what to do" - for the entire data set you want to compute - not "how to do it" in a step by step, row by row fashion.

Answer (score 5):

IS NOT NULL

As NULL would indicate the absense of a value.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if null using `IS NULL` as follows;

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(20)

SET @name = (SELECT Product_Name FROM tb_new_product_Name_id where Product_Name=@productName)

IF @name IS NULL -- # Here is where you check it
BEGIN
    -- # Handle null @name
END 
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- # @name has value
END
```

This how i would do, but if you are declaring `@name` variable only for null checking then i would go as [Demien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007641/how-to-check-variable-has-value-in-sql-server-2008-stored-procedure/22007926#22007926) suggests. Using `EXISTS` you don't even need the `@name` variable

Comment: It's not even for `NULL` checking - they're selecting the same column in the `SELECT` clause that is also the filter in the `WHERE` clause - to my eyes, this is *purely* an existence check.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever good point, i totaly missed that. Unless it's `NULL` then; `@name` has to be equal to `@productName`. Then `@name` is a unnecessary temp var there.

Answer (score 1):

An uninitiated variable always has null value in it. You may use IS NOT NULL to check that..

Answer (score 0):

Recently encountered a situation where a field with no values was being checked with is null, is not null but was not working and on debugging found if no value then the field was getting a 0. So checking for value = '' or value = 0 or value is null, one of the three would check if its empty.