# Only assign a variable if it is a numeric value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
declare @ShouldBeNumber as varchar(10)
set @ShouldBeNumber = 1

declare @Number as varchar(10)

select @Number = case when ISNUMERIC(@ShouldBeNumber) then @Number = @ShouldBeNumber else @Number = '' end
```

i.e. only assign the variable if it is numeric. I have spent the last hour Googling this and have not found anything.

For example, I have looked here: [How to check if a variable has a value in a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007641/how-to-check-if-a-variable-has-a-value-in-a-sql-server-2008-stored-procedure)

Comment: Does your code not work?  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
select @Number = (case when ISNUMERIC(@ShouldBeNumber) = 1
                       then @ShouldBeNumber else @Number
                  end)
```

I assume `isnumeric()` does what you want, although it might have some unwanted behavior depending on your needs (accepting negative numbers, decimals, and exponential notation for instance).  The `else` clause is a no-op; it just assigns the existing value back to `@Number`.

Comment: @w0051977 Just make sure this does what you want.  This will result in @ number being null if @ ShouldBeNumber is not a number. Your post made it look like you want it to be a empty string

Comment: @Kevin, thanks.  I changed my code to: else Number (with an @ sign at the beginning) after I reviewed the answer earlier today.

Comment: are you able to take a look at my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61273521/stop-sql-server-creating-a-distributed-transaction-when-a-remote-stored-prcoedur ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `try_cast()` function as shown below.

```
DECLARE @ShouldBeNumber AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @ShouldBeNumber = 'A'
DECLARE @number AS VARCHAR(10)

Select @number = isnull(cast(try_cast(@ShouldBeNumber as float) as varchar(10)),'')

SELECT @number
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ec9019ef06b5d5fad0dba2d7113aabc) demo.

Comment: you don't really need the case statement. you can just do select @ number = isnull(cast(try_cast(@ShouldBeNumber as int) as varchar),'')

Comment: @Kevin Changed as per your suggestion to improve the answer.